# Why is my if else statement not working? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if else statement that is supposed to hide/show list items when other list items are appended/removed.  It only works if I put the if else statement after the #delete-square function but it only works for one list item.  Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matty91/zqmps11b/6/

This is probably really simple to do but I don't know javascript/jquery that well.

Example: So for every blue square that is added, take away a green square.  There should always be 4 squares present.  (if I have 2 blue I should have 2 green.  If I have 4 blue then I should have no green.  The user should be able to add as many blue squares as he wants but if the blue squares go below 3 then add 1 green) Hopefully that makes sense :)

Let me know if I need to explain a bit more for what I'm trying to accomplish!

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("ul.db-view-list li .quad #chart_div").length == 1){
      $("li.ph:last-child").hide();
    } else if($("ul.db-view-list li .quad #chart_div").length == 2){
      $("li.ph:nth-child(2)").hide();
    } else if($("ul.db-view-list li .quad #chart_div").length == 3){
      $("li.ph:nth-child(1)").hide();
    } else if($("ul.db-view-list li .quad #chart_div").length >= 4){
      $("li.ph:first-child").hide();
    } else {
      $("li.ph").show();
    };
  $(".add-square").click(function(){
    $(".db-view-list").prepend("<li><button id='delete-square'>X</button><div class='quad'><div id='chart_div'></div></div></li>");
    $(document).on('click', '#delete-square', function(){
     $(this).parent().remove();
   }); 
  });
});
```

```css
.db-view-list{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 300px;
}

.db-view-list li{
  padding:0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.quad{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.default-message{
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#chart_div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#delete-square{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="db-view-list">
  <li class="ph">
    <div class="quad">
      <p class="default-message">
        click add square to add a graph first
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="ph">
    <div class="quad">
      <p class="default-message">
        click add square to add a graph 2 
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="ph">
    <div class="quad">
      <p class="default-message">
        click add square to add a graph 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li class="ph">
    <div class="quad">
      <p class="default-message">
        click add square to add a graph last
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button class="add-square">
  add square
</button>
```

Comment: You don't have anything with an ID of `chart_div` and ID's can only be used once so if you do have multiple things with that ID, it will only select one of them.

Comment: Yes, please explain in more detail. When I click the 'Add Square' button, it is adding a square! And when I click the 'X' it removes the square!

Comment: Matty are you saying that you want there to only ever be 4 boxes on the screen? So that when one is added it hides the oldest?

Comment: @MikeC Yes I do a have a chart_div.  It is prepended on the .add-square click function.  I didn't know id's can only be used once.  I thought that was only for css.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AdamJeffers I will update my question with more detail.

Comment: @zfrisch Yes that's what I'm trying to accomplish! Sorry for the poor explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zqmps11b/28/

Keep in mind the CSS is changed as well to accommodate Classes instead of IDs.

Your if statements were setup to only be checked on document.ready which only occurs once. This should work:

```
 var numOfNewBoxes = 0;
// declare variable to count new boxes. 

$(document).ready(function () {
 // the if/else statement should be removed from the document.ready function
 //You're not reloading the page every time you tap the 'add square button

  //change the ids to classes because there should only be 1 instance of each ID. 
  $(".add-square").click(function () {
    $(".db-view-list").prepend("<li><button class='delete-square'>X</button><div class='quad'><div class='chart_div'></div></div></li>");
    //hide the last of the original boxes that are visible
    $('.default-message:visible:last').hide();
    numOfNewBoxes ++;
    //remove any old on click events attached to the class delete-square
    $('.delete-square').off('click');
    //assign the event to the delete square class only - not the document.
    //This stops the event from continuously firing on click.
    $('.delete-square').on('click', function () {


      numOfNewBoxes --;
      //show the first of the original boxes if they are hidden
      // only if there are < 4 new boxes;
      $(this).parent().remove();
      (numOfNewBoxes < 4) ? ($('.default-message:hidden:first').show()) : false;


    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this is very close to what I'm looking for! Thanks! One quick question: In you jsfiddle, if I add 3 blue and then delete 2 blue I should have 1 blue with 3 green. For some reason it is bringing all the green back though.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: @matty just saw this. I'll take a look in a little bit and update later.

Comment: @matty This has been updated. Let me know if you need any more help or if something doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to have more than one chart_div and delete_button, you can't use that as an id. Use a class instead:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chartDivs = $("ul.db-view-list li .quad .chart_div"); 
        if (chartDivs.length == 1) {
            $("li.ph:last-child").hide();
        } else if (chartDivs.length == 2) {
            $("li.ph:nth-child(2)").hide();
        } else if (chartDivs.length == 3) {
            $("li.ph:nth-child(1)").hide();
        } else if (chartDivs.length >= 4) {
            $("li.ph:first-child").hide();
        } else {
            $("li.ph").show();
        }
        ;
        $(".add-square").click(function () {
            $(".db-view-list").prepend("<li><button class='delete-square'>X</button><div class='quad'><div class='chart_div'></div></div></li>");

        });
        //this will apply to .delete-squares created in the future
        //so you can just do it once.
        $(document).on('click', '.delete-square', function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should also put that if/else statement in a function and have it execute whenever you delete or add a div. Now, the if/else statement is only executed once: when the document is ready.